# What's the difference between JSON_VALUE and JSON_TEXTCONTAINS in Oracle 12c?

Tags: sql, json, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am using Oracle 12c and SQL Developer, also I am persisting a JSON in a column

```
CREATE TABLE APPLICATION(
  id varchar2(36) PRIMARY KEY, 
  APPLICATION clob,
  constraint APPLICATION check (APPLICATION is JSON)
);
```

Then I have inserted some rows

```
insert into APPLICATION values(SYS_GUID(), <huge JSON>);
```

I want to make a query to get the specific field from json column.

```
Select app.application
From APPLICATION app
Where (JSON_VALUE(app.application, '$.fields.CustomerID') IN ('Bank0', 'Bank1', 'Bank2', 'Bank3', '001pepebottle', '08092015CoappOrg', 'ConsortiumOrg')) 
AND JSON_VALUE(app.application, '$.arrays.PII.arrays.PN.fields.DocumentId', '213213');
```

but I got:

```
Error en la línea de comandos:4 Columna:75
Informe de error:
Error SQL: ORA-00907: falta el paréntesis derecho
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Using JSON_TEXTCONTAINS I got many bad results (I know they are wrong because I haven't persisted a JSOn with field `DocumentID` equals `213213`)

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JSON_TEXTCONTAINS` is a conditiion](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions010.htm#SQLRF56963); while [`JSON_VALUE` is a function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions093.htm#SQLRF56668).

You seem to be treating your second call to `JSON_VALUE` as a condition - you aren't comparing its result with anything, and you're passing too many arguments, which is causing the ORA-00907 error. The error is reported against line 4 column 75, which is the comma after `....DocumentId'`.

It looks like you actually want to compare the value it returns with your fixed string:

```
AND JSON_VALUE(app.application, '$.arrays.PII.arrays.PN.fields.DocumentId') = '213213'
```

or

```
AND JSON_VALUE(app.application, '$.arrays.PII.arrays.PN.fields.DocumentId' NUMBER) = 213213
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very instring answer